# What can I do to pin Facebook on Windows 8 as a live tile on the Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8-preview, facebook, live-tiles

In Windows Phone 7's menu, Facebook is pinned and it shows how many notifications or messages you have – without Facebook being opened.

How can I do the same in Windows 8?

I pinned it to the menu, but it's just a blue square.

Comment: You need to wait for someone to write a Facebook Metro application. If you have some HTML / CSS / JS knowledge or C# + XML knowledge it could be possible to do this yourself.

Comment: Have you tried FlipToast? It's in the Store